# Does there exist a "content transfer" like a neural style transfer?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-models, neural-style-transfer

Normally, a neural style operation works by taking a content image and a style image.
A third image is optimized to have the same content as the content image and the same style as the style image by optimizing the content of the content image and the style of the style image.

However, for one particular application, I want to do "content transfer". Content transfer means that in particular, out of the two images designated content image and style image respectively, I want to create an image which has the content of the content image, but it also contains content features from the style image. Not just the style features.

Is there any existing body of work on this?